# What is difference between "train_test_split(shuffle=False)" and "TimeSeriesSplit"

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

When I tried two ways of splitting my time series data, prediction result with test dataset was different. When I checked my data, method1 and 2 shows same result of splitting data. But, the prediction result by test dataset were different. So, what is difference between using `train_test_split(shuffle=False)` and `TimeSeriesSplit`?

Here are what I tried:
Dataset for split

```
X = df_5T.drop('demand', axis=1)
y = df_5T.demand
```

1. train_test_split

   ```
   X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.167, shuffle=False, random_state=0)
   ```
2. TimeSeriesSplit

   ```
   from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
   tscv = TimeSeriesSplit()
   for train_index, val_index in tscv.split(X):
     print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", val_index)
     X_train, X_val = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[val_index]
     y_train, y_val = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[val_index]

   ##Result##
   TRAIN: [   0    1    2 ... 1485 1486 1487] TEST: [1488 1489 1490 ... 2973 2974 2975]
   TRAIN: [   0    1    2 ... 2973 2974 2975] TEST: [2976 2977 2978 ... 4461 4462 4463]
   TRAIN: [   0    1    2 ... 4461 4462 4463] TEST: [4464 4465 4466 ... 5949 5950 5951]
   TRAIN: [   0    1    2 ... 5949 5950 5951] TEST: [5952 5953 5954 ... 7437 7438 7439]
   TRAIN: [   0    1    2 ... 7437 7438 7439] TEST: [7440 7441 7442 ... 8925 8926 8927]
   ```

When I checked data after timeseriessplit, X_train, X_val followed last fold.

```
X_train.info()
####
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 7440 entries, 2020-01-01 00:00:00+09:00 to 2020-01-26 19:55:00+09:00
####

X_train.info()
####
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 1488 entries, 2020-01-26 20:00:00+09:00 to 2020-01-31 23:55:00+09:00
####
```

Test data

```
X_test = data02_5T.drop('demand', axis=1)
y_test = data02_5T.demand
```

model fit and predict code

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_val)
y_test = model.predict(X_test)
print(rmsle(y_val, y_pred))
print(rmsle(y_test, y_test))
```

Method1 result

```
val: 10.659636522389675
test: 136.65172778040608
```

Method2 result

```
val: 12.655831132167329
test: 18.771364489679307
```

Comment: Both splits are different that's why you get different results. You have a different number of entries when you call `X_train.info()`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I checked X_train.info() for method1 and 2, but X_train range was almost same (method1: ~2020-01-25 19:05 / method2: ~2020-01-26 19:55). And both methods used same test dataset. What I am concerning about is that test result are too different in spite of almost similar train and test datasets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For time-series related machine learning, you have to use the `timeseriesplit()` method. Otherwise, it is data leaking. You will get a very high score in lab environment but fail in the real-world stage. Comparing method 1 and method 2 has shown it clearly:

> Method1 result val: 10.659636522389675(high score as data leaking)
> test: 136.65172778040608(failed score as your model is not generalized)
>
> Method2 result val: 12.655831132167329 (low compare the method1 as not
> data leaking) test: 18.771364489679307( reasonable score, less than
> validation but good in the real world)

Why method 1 failed and it is data leaking?

Here is the answer.
`train_test_split()` do not design for time series data. it just randomly split data.

Let's say, you want to train data and predict the future. The train data has 5 days data in Jan.
[image]
`train_test_split()` may use Jan 1st, Jan 2st, Jan 3rd, Jan fifth as training data, to predict Jan fourth. In the real world, Jan Forth is strongly related to Jan 1,2,3,5. That' lead to data leaks.

In reality work, you will only predict the future, instead of the past. So, `train_test_split()` showed a good validation score but failed in real data when predicting the future.

`TimeSeriesSplit()` on the roll. It splits data-based accumulated. it makes sure you train/predict the future instead of the past. In this way, the model trained could be useful to predict future data.
[image]

Here is the detailed documentation regarding [`TimeSeriesSplit()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_cv_indices.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-cv-indices-py).

If you like my answer, pls vote for it.

Best Regards,

WangYong

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Mr.Wang! I have a question about train_test_split. I added "shuffle=False" in train_test_split which means "do not shuffle dataset randomly". Does I misunderstand about the meaning of "shuffle=False" in train_test_split?

Comment: In default parameter , you set shuffle = False, the data will not shuffle. So there is randomly shuffle is disabled as well.  here is the doc https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html and example.  >>> train_test_split(y, shuffle=False)
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4]].

Comment: Yes, then if I set shuffle=False, I think there are no data leak between train and test. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. you are right. In this way, there is no data leak.  Now, you can explor cross validation from just split data. In sklearn, train_test_split is belong to split functions(basic functions). and Kfold, TimeSeries relation cross validation is belong to advanced splitter classs. They are designed for different purpose.  Here is the API catlog URL for your reference. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.model_selection